# gpg-agent fail: undefined symbol gpg_err_set_errno

Tags: centos

We started to get some odd issues yesterday; possible due to a yum install gone bad?  One of the issues, PS -ef hanging indefinately (actually an ps command that looks at other user state) was fixed with a reboot.  However we still have two issuse.

When trying to run vncserver I get an error that:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load modle "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object.
```

This error is valid; because the libcanberra-gtk-module does not exist anywhere on our system.  I would just remove the module from the list to load, as I think it's non-mandatory, but I don't know what is causing vncserver to try to load it.

The more important error though is GPG-agent.  We get the error a few places, but it boils down to the fact that when I try to run gpg-agent I get the error:

```
 ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so.11: undefined symbole: gog-err-set_errno
```

none of the files listed on the gpg-agent man page even seem to exist.  We tried re-installing libgpg-error package which didn't fix anything.  Any idea what would cause this, or how to debug it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install every package from the same repository?

Comment: I added a new yum repository, though one that is suppose to be used by cent-os 6.2 as well, right before doing the install (my current repository didn't have the RPM I wanted).  I think all the new RPM (4 were installed, due to dependencies) used the new repository.  I guess this is how it broke?  would love to know how though.  Shouldn't YUM check dependencies and ensure no matter what repository you don't install an inappropriate RPM?

Comment: _What_ repository did you add? EPEL is careful not to replace official packages, others might be much less so...

Comment: actually, the system I'm working on is not connected to the internet.  I used an intranet repository maintained by someone on the intranet. Still, I'm pretty sure if they did anything too idiotic it would be a problem.  To be exact I think I went from the default list of RPM fully tested to a mirror of EPEL, but not certain of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue.  The problem was that my LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable was blank.  setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64 fixed the problem, as my libgpg_error SO was in my /lib64 directory.  To be more exact gpg-agent new where to find libgpg_error.so (according to LDD).  However, gpg-agent also used libgcrypt.  Libgcrypt was unable to find the libgpg_error.so; and since libgcrypt.so shows up before libgpg_error.so on the symbol table I suppose libgcrypt.so loaded first and threwup because it hadn't loaded and couldn't find libgpg_error.so.  setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH allowed libgcrypt to find and load the .so properly.

I've set a tiny script in /etc/profile.d/ that runs

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;/lib64
```

I haven't done a reboot; but once it happens that should fix the problem perminatley for everyone I believe.

If anyone can tell me why yum (if yum did it) broke this I would love to know.  Also, should I be worried that right now my LD_LIBRARY_PATH consists of only the /lib64 path?  should there be other paths there?  should I wonder why it was empty before I added my script?

update: my solution of adding to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH file wasn't perfect, LD_LIBRARY_PATH would still be empty when I opened a terminal in gnome.  The proper way to fix this was/is to put a file into /etc/ld.so.cache.d/ directory; the file had to end with .conf (to be detected) and contain the line

```
/lib64
```

Then I ran ldconfig as root.  This properly ensures that linux 'auto detects' all the .so in /lib64; without my needing to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH at all.

Comment: That path should be searched by default, so if it isn't something strange is going on. And if it isn't searched by default, most of the system would fall over...

Comment: yep, this still isn't fixed.  when I connect via SSH I'm fine, but when I create a VNCServer and open a terminal within the server LD_LIBRARY__PATH still isn't set; depsite being set by profile.d script.  I think that means something would have to be saving over it later?  it means I can start vncserver; but things within vnc (like rapidsvn, the start of all of this) still don't work because of the GPG error.  I can set it in my bash.rc file; but I want something that fixes it for everyone...